# Finding the perfect matching

Tags: graphs

This the following graph where I want to find the perfect matching and a maximum matching

[image]

I converted this to an bipartite graph, and found that the perfect matching exists and also found an maximum matching, but I am unable to justify that it is indeed maximum. How can you justify that a given matching is indeed maximum?

Comment: What do you mean by "I converted this to a bipartite graph?". The graph that you showed **IS** bipartite.

Comment: @Steven Yeah, that was what I meant, I meant that to find it the perfect matching, I found that it is bipartite and would have a perfect matching. but now I am unable to justify that the given matching is maximum.

Comment: Can you show the matching that you found? I don't think that the graph admits a perfect matching. At least one of the 3 inner edges must be selected in any perfect matching. Then two of the edges going from a vertex that is a corner of the triangle towards the center must be selected as well. This means that there are two edges (lying on a "side" of the triangle) that cannot be selected. Since these two edges are exactly the ones incident to a vertex of the graph (the vertex at the center a the side of triangle), this vertex cannot be matched.

Answer (score 1):

To show that a certain matching $M$ is maximum in a graph $G$, it is necessary and sufficient to show that there is no [augmenting path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berge%27s_lemma) relative to $M$: a path in $G$ that starts and ends on free (unmatched) vertices, and alternates between edges in and not in $M$.

Answer (score 1):

The graph admits no perfect matching.
Look at the following figure and notice that any perfect matching must match vertex $x$. By symmetry suppose it does so with the blue edge $(x,y)$. Then, since $u$ and $v$ need to be matched, the matching must necessarily contain the two remaining blue edges.
However, in this situation, vertex $w$ cannot be matched anymore. Therefore any matching has at least one unmatched vertex.

[image: counterexample]

From the above discussion we know that the maximum size of a matching one can hope for is $\left\lfloor\frac{10-1}{2}\right\rfloor = 4$.

Here is a possible (maximum) matching of size $4$:

[image: matching]